# Shared neovim/nvim and vim config-file, issue with coc.nvim: "(coc-definition)" works in vim - but not in neovim, why?

Tags: vimrc, neovim

Noob, please bear over with me: I'm trying to share my ~/.vimrc config by sourcing it from ~/.config/nvim/init.vim. I try to use [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) and it works for vim, but not for neovim/nvim (using a sourced config-file). I don't know where to look or what is the problem. The **~/.config/nvim/init.vim** is:

```
set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
let &packpath=&runtimepath
source ~/.vimrc
```

The ***~/.vimrc*** file:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
call plug#end()

" Get LSP support:
let g:coc_start_at_startup = 0
augroup coc
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimEnter * :silent CocStart
augroup end

" ---=== Below is directly from: https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim ===---
nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)
nmap <silent> gy <Plug>(coc-type-definition)
nmap <silent> gi <Plug>(coc-implementation)
nmap <silent> gr <Plug>(coc-references)
```

1. If I open a source code file using vim, after around 10 seconds in the lower left corner it says: "***[coc.nvim] FORTLS initialization complete"***, which tells that the LSP/language server is now running, it's working and I can use the "coc-definition" etc commands to jump around.
2. If I open exactly the same file using nvim, it doesn't work: I wait and wait, it never says "initialization complete" and also the "gd" or "coc-definition" commands won't work, so I can't jump around...

Seems like nvim isn't loading the FORTLS (language server), but vim is? Why? How can I debug this or understand what is wrong? Thanks for any ideas!

**UPDATE**: Someone downvoted this question: I'm not trying to be disrespectful, I appreciate instead please giving me constructive feedback, if I should rephrase - but I've edited the original post, to make things clearer. Also: I suspect neovim/nvim isn't loading ~/.vim/coc-settings.json but I thought sourcing like shown would fix that and is it possible to see some kind of vim/neovim initialization log? So, the /home/user/.vim/coc-settings.json must be okay (since vim uses it). I also found out that I could "debug" a bit using the output from ":CocInfo" - this also reveals that the language server using nvim doesn't start at all... There are no errors/warnings, just nothing happens - the difference should be very clear from the below?

```
=== 1: vim ===
## versions

vim version: VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 8022380
node version: v15.7.0
coc.nvim version: 0.0.80-1e2652e725
coc.nvim directory: /home/user/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim
term: dumb
platform: linux

## Log of coc.nvim

2021-02-19T21:39:22.868 INFO (pid:1355597) [services] - registered service "languageserver.fortran"
2021-02-19T21:39:22.872 INFO (pid:1355597) [services] - fortran state change: stopped => starting
2021-02-19T21:39:22.907 INFO (pid:1355597) [plugin] - coc.nvim 0.0.80-1e2652e725 initialized with node: v15.7.0 after 100ms
2021-02-19T21:39:22.913 INFO (pid:1355597) [language-client-index] - Language server "languageserver.fortran" started with 1355608
2021-02-19T21:39:27.165 INFO (pid:1355597) [attach] - receive notification: showInfo []


=== 2: nvim ===
## versions

vim version: NVIM v0.4.4
node version: v15.7.0
coc.nvim version: 0.0.80-1e2652e725
coc.nvim directory: /home/user/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim
term: xterm-256color
platform: linux

## Log of coc.nvim

2021-02-19T21:39:59.762 INFO (pid:1355680) [plugin] - coc.nvim 0.0.80-1e2652e725 initialized with node: v15.7.0 after 113ms
2021-02-19T21:40:02.607 INFO (pid:1355680) [attach] - receive notification: showInfo []
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I wonder if you'll have more luck talking to the coc developers? They might be able to explain the discrepancy.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Thanks a lot! I'll think about it, but they have 26 issues (at https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/issues) and as I'm a vim noob (migrating from emacs) I'm also a bit afraid of wasting their time, if the solution is simple... Will wait a bit, thanks and good suggestion, though...

Comment: Just commenting to say thank you for the question! It infuriates me to no end that the SO community will anonymously downvote well intentioned questions like this. I'm getting the same error setting up nvim, and questions like this are super helpful for figuring out what the problem might be. <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops, sorry guys - I did write I'm a new user. I figured out the problem, after I realized I could get some kind of "debug" output with ":CocInfo". The solution was just to:

```
cd ~/.config/nvim
ln -s ~/.vim/coc-settings.json .
```

It means that the

```
set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
let &packpath=&runtimepath
source ~/.vimrc
```

Probably only works for normal vim-stuff - and coc.nvim has a special configuration file "coc-settings.json" that isn't sourced and nvim will *not* search in the runtimepath, which I didn't find to be intuitive... I'll leave the answer here, if another noob does the same silly mistake and finds this...

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble : Thanks a lot, after I figured out the ":CocInfo"-trick to see what was going on behind the scenes it was so much easier to realize that the (language server) service didn't start and from that point making experiments was easy and understanding the solution was relatively easy... Am very happy with a "working" config now, both for vim+nvim, as I continue to explore vim and experiment with my config-file(s)...